# VS2019:fatal error C1083 Cannot open header file: 'opencv.hpp'

Tags: c++, visual-studio

It is all fine when I was writing the code, that is, when I included the header file "opencv2/opencv.hpp",
and VS2019 can indeed "see" it,
in other words, I can use the class that is in the opencv.hpp, but only when I complied the project,c1083 occurred

before i added the function DrawLine(),i compiled for times,with no err.and then i added the function DrawLine(..),error occurred

this is the total source code

a.h
a.cpp

```
//a.h
#include<opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

class Canvas{
    Mat mat_canvas;

    void Init(){
        mat_canvas.create(1024,1024,CV_32FC3);
    }

    void DrawLine(float ax,float ay,float bx,float by);
}
```

```
//a.cpp
#include"a.h"

void Canvas::DrawLine(float ax,float ay,float bx,float by){
    cv::line(this->mat_canvas,Point2f(ax,ax),Point2f(bx,by),Scalar(1,1,1));
}
```

error msg was:

```
fatal error C1083 Cannot open header file: 'opencv.hpp': no such file or dir
```

i know i can create a new solution and move my old solution to it,but it takes time,and i can't actually know whether this issue will happen again in my new solution

Any answer will be helpful

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, give us some more information (share with us the code, the visual-studio solution...). Maybe reed the information on how to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @apalomer ok i added the code

Comment: Can you show us the complete error message?

Comment: @Mannoj :ok i did it

Comment: The preprocessor is running as phase 1 in the compiler. So there are no different results (in finding the file) for preprocessor and compiler. So how did you check that the preprocessor can find the header file during writing the code? Was it in fact the IDE (Intellisense) that found the header file, but not the compiler? Also what build system are you using? vcxproj file, makefile, cmake?

Comment: @wernerHenze im using vs2019 and maybe in fact the intellisense found the header file,but how to solve this problem?the time when i was writing was fine with no error msg,only when i compiled the code,err occurred

Comment: Post your project file's content. This sounds a lot like a path-issue that comes from not configuring your project properly.

Comment: @rbaleksandar i compiled for times,with no err.and then i added the function DrawLine(..),error occurred

Comment: i know i can create a new solution and move my old solution to it,but it takes time,and i can't actually know whether this issue will happen again in my new solution

Comment: @Suric "Additional include directory path" is not resolved or not mentioned in project setup.
https://support.pixelink.com/support/solutions/articles/3000044961-configuring-visual-studio-for-c-c-projects

Comment: @Mannoj i added the include path,i checked the path for times and i am sure there is err with include path.

Comment: @Mannoj thx a lot ,problem solved,i reset the additional include path following the link you gived,and compile successfully somehow.

Comment: @Suric Posted the answer so other people can find the resolution easily; you can accept it if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there are most of the time possibility of missing "Additional include directory path" or wrongly setup.

**Where to find in Visual Studio:**

To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment

1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see Set
   C++ compiler and build properties in Visual Studio.
2. Select the Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General property page.
3. Modify the Additional Include Directories property.

[Visual Studio 2019 C++ Project configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=vs-2019)

Example project setup is described in below link:
[Example setup](https://support.pixelink.com/support/solutions/articles/3000044961-configuring-visual-studio-for-c-c-projects)