# Cannot include headers in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header-files, visual-studio-2019

I was making some program in C++. I needed to include some header (`#include <gnuplot>`). But when I do this with `#include` and brackets `<gnuplot>`, I get the error, that this header doesn't exist. I need to specify the whole path from the program file to the `main` file. But if I move this project to the other place, I need to specify everything again, so this is pretty annoying.

Do I have to write something in the `main` file of the header, that I can include it with the brackets? In which folder do I need to download all the libraries. Check the **Data** for my whole tree.

This has happened with other headers, too.

How can I do this?

---

**Data:**

I have some large folder named `C++` and inside in individual folders my projects. I have also one folder `Libraries` in this `C++` folder and inside in separate folders some libraries.

My tree:

```
C++
|-Project1
  |-Project1
    |-*the main program*
  |-Some other folders
|-Project2, etc.
|-Libraries
  |-gnuplot
    |-other libraries
```

I use Visual Studio 2019.

Hope that this data helps. If you need some more data, just tell this in the comment section. Tell some improvement to this question, too.

Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Note that these headers aren't defined by me, but are downloaded from web.

Comment: You need to tell your compiler where to search for includes. It cannot magically guess where you placed random stuff.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=vs-2019

Comment: Works on my machine.  I'm using `clang++`, and specified `--cxx-isystem ${ROOT}/Libraries` and it found the `#include <gnuplot>` header in there no problem.  How did you tell VS2019 where to find those `#include<>` headers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559101/vs2019fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-header-file-opencv-hpp/60564322#60564322

Comment: I suggest you could add the path to where gnuplot is located to your project additional include directories. (Just right-click on the project -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify extra directories to search for `#include` files in the projects' properties: Right-click on the project in the solution explorer and select the "Properties" command; then open the `C/C++` node and select the "General" tab. You can then add directories to search in the "Additional Include Directories" field, like this:

[image]

In your case, you can use the `..\` prefix to 'go up' one level from your projects' folder, and then 'down into' the `Libraries` folder. You can add multiple directory paths: separate them with the semicolon `;` character.

Comment: Do I have to do this for the each project?

Comment: @Let'sCode • only the projects that have their own gnuplot library headers in that relative location.

Comment: @Eljay But then it is easier to write just the relative path like this: #include "*relative path/file.h*".

Comment: @Let'sCode It's actually very easy to copy your "Additional Include Directories" values from one project to another: just select the path(s) you want in the edit field above, type `Ctrl+C` then select anther project in the Solution Explorer (you don't need to close the property pop-up) and and paste (using `Ctrl+V`) the path into the field for that project.

Comment: @Let'sCode • that is an option.  There are pros & cons for either way.  The way as per the question scales better, but for smaller projects scaling better is not compelling.