# How can I resolve this compile error in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to compile [CFortranTranslator](https://github.com/CalvinNeo/CFortranTranslator) in Visual Studio 2015.

Getting the following error:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CFortranTranslator, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: cpptest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Process "for90.y" bison file
2>  main.cpp
1>C:\Users\pc\source\repos\CFortranTranslator\src\grammar\custom_build_rules\win_flex_bison_custom_build.targets(55,5): error MSB3721: The command "
1>C:\Users\pc\source\repos\CFortranTranslator\src\grammar\custom_build_rules\win_flex_bison_custom_build.targets(55,5): error MSB3721: start /B /WAIT /D "C:\Users\pc\source\repos\CFortranTranslator\src\grammar\" win_bison.exe --output="for90.tab.cpp" --defines="for90.tab.h"  "for90.y"
1>C:\Users\pc\source\repos\CFortranTranslator\src\grammar\custom_build_rules\win_flex_bison_custom_build.targets(55,5): error MSB3721: exit /b %errorlevel%" exited with code 1.
2>  cpptest.vcxproj -> C:\Users\pc\source\repos\CFortranTranslator\vsbuild\x64\Debug\cpptest.exe
2>  cpptest.vcxproj -> C:\Users\pc\source\repos\CFortranTranslator\vsbuild\x64\Debug\cpptest.pdb (Partial PDB)
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

the flex-bison is already in the designated directory:

[image]

So, what should I do to resolve this?

**EDIT:** After following Robert's instructions, the errors related to Flex/Bison are gone. Thanks to him.

But, now, I see that the application is not finding Boost, even though it is installed already.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: CFortranTranslator, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  Process "for90.y" bison file
1>  Process "for90.l" flex file
1>  lazygen.cpp
1>  gen_variable.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_vardef.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_type.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_suite.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_stmt.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_select.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_program.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_paramtable.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_label.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_io.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_if.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_function.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_feature.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_exp.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_doc.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_do.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_dimenslice.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_config.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_callable.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Compiling...
1>  gen_attr_describer.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_arraybuilder.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  gen_common.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  Variable.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  tokenizer.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  parser.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  Intent.cpp
1>  Function.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  attribute.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  simple_lexer.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  for90.tab.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\src\grammar\for90.tab.cpp': No such file or directory
1>  getopt2.cpp
1>  develop.cpp
1>c:\users\pc\source\repos\calvinneo\cfortrantranslator\src\parser\variable.h(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/optional/optional.hpp': No such file or directory
1>  forstdio.cpp
1>  forlang.cpp
1>  forfilesys.cpp
1>  for90std.cpp
1>  farray.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**EDIT-2**:

I resolved Boost-issue.

Now, I am having the following error:

```
for90.tab.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\src\grammar\for90.tab.cpp': No such file or directory
```

Comment: looks simiar to the error described in a similar repo https://github.com/lexxmark/winflexbison/blob/master/custom_build_rules/README.md they provide some suggestions

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken, this guideline doesn't work.

Comment: @user366312, could you share the outputted error after you increased the MSBuild project build output verbosity (as suggested in the link chickity shared)?

Comment: @diogoslima, the output is the same as I already supplied.

Comment: Ohh, I was not expecting it to be the same. Doble checking for sanity: if you open a Command Prompt in that same location and run ‘win_bison.exe’, passing those same arguments, all run successfully without any errors outputted by ‘win_bison.exe’? Basically, it is confirmed the problem is related to the Custom Build Event?

Comment: @diogoslima, actually, the custom build event is already configured in the GitHub repo. The command is probably hard-coded. Coz, I can't change it.

Comment: Did you try to add the parent of boost folder to include directories:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60624208/cannot-include-headers-in-c

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk, I resolved Boost issue. Now, it says `for90.tab.cpp
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\src\grammar\for90.tab.cpp': No such file or directory`.

Comment: The problem is in `win-bison`: `win_bison: ...\CFortranTranslator\src\grammar\data/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4: cannot open: No such file or directory`

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk, Thanks. I solved the problem.

Comment: You need to download folder `data` from: `https://github.com/lexxmark/winflexbison/tree/bison2.7/bison` and copy it to: `...\CFortranTranslator\src\grammar`

Comment: !@RobertAndrzejuk, Yes. I got that already. Anyways, the `CFortranTranslator` software is full of bugs. Our effort was in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file:

```
... \CFortranTranslator\src\grammar\custom_build_rules\win_flex_bison_custom_build.props
```

1. Go to line 16,17,18 which reads

   ```
      <CommandLineTemplate>
      start /B /WAIT /D "%(RootDir)%(Directory)" win_bison.exe [AllOptions] [AdditionalOptions] "%(Filename)%(Extension)"
      exit /b %errorlevel%</CommandLineTemplate>
   ```

Replace with (only 1 line):

```
  <CommandLineTemplate>start /B /WAIT /D "%(RootDir)%(Directory)" win_bison.exe [AllOptions] [AdditionalOptions] "%(Filename)%(Extension)" &amp; exit /b %errorlevel%</CommandLineTemplate>
```

2. On (now) lines 34,35,36:

   ```
      <CommandLineTemplate>
      start /B /WAIT /D "%(RootDir)%(Directory)" win_flex.exe [AllOptions] [AdditionalOptions] "%(Filename)%(Extension)"
      exit /b %errorlevel%</CommandLineTemplate>
   ```

Replace with (only 1 line):

```
  <CommandLineTemplate>start /B /WAIT /D "%(RootDir)%(Directory)" win_flex.exe [AllOptions] [AdditionalOptions] "%(Filename)%(Extension)" &amp; exit /b %errorlevel%</CommandLineTemplate>
```

3. Save the file and BUILD