# C++ project is not finding its header files (visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have not used C++ in visual studio in a lonnng lonnng time so probably this is a basic question but I would like some help.

I am opening someone else C++ code and the first thing I notice is that it is not recognizing its includes.

For example I have a `main.cpp` that has

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "myheader.h"
```

this cpp file is inside a "source" folder and those header files are under a "headers" folder.

I got an error "cannot open source file "stdafx.h" and "cannot open source file "myheader.h"

It is been ages I haven't touched C++ in visual studio. What configuration I should do to fix this?

Comment: Does `stdafx.h` exist?

Comment: There is an `Additional Include Directories` setting. Make sure it contains the folder that has the include files shown above or that the include files shown above are in the same folder as the source files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS2019:fatal error C1083 Cannot open header file: 'opencv.hpp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559101/vs2019fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-header-file-opencv-hpp)

Answer (score 1):

if `source` and `headers` folders are in same level in folder structure you can use

```
#include "..\headers\myheader.h"
```

Similarly locate your `stdafx.h` and add the relative path to the .cpp file.